# Advise on Creating a Career Advice site for Developers

Tags: discussion, career

I have seen for a long time Questions like Tools advice and career advice are being given -ve marks and called off-topic, but these questions are always in developers' mind and can't go away. So I advise you or the admin, who can do this, create a Career Advice website like other web sites under StackExchange.com. 
I hope other developers and designers will have similar views. Feel free to comment or give -ve marks, I am waiting.

But still believe StackExchange.com is one of the best site which helps people of different disciplines. Now Careers and others advice should also be treated seriously and such questions should be allowed where people can communicate their views. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster has some good points

Comment: I think when career related questions are asked, they should be answered in such a way that they help other developers too.

Comment: are you aware about [Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I would also point to [Why was my question closed as off topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/) - additionally, what type of 'career advice' are you thinking of?  [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) is the tool and process for proposing a new stack exchange site.

Comment: Thanks for http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmers *used* to be the career advice site. However, the goals changed and now career advice questions get marked off topic and closed. [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is the replacement as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions